# SSH Error Any ideas?

Tags: oracle, ssh, oracle-enterprise-manager

i am having the following error when trying to install an oracle agent !!

```
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sshd[23880]: Accepted publickey for em12c-srvc from 10.xxxxxxx port 16263 ssh2
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sshd[23880]: Accepted publickey for em12c-srvc from 10.xxxxxxx port 16263 ssh2
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sshd[23880]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user em12c-srvc by (uid=0)
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sshd[23880]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user em12c-srvc by (uid=0)
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sudo: em12c-srvc : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/em12c-srvc ; USER=em12c-srvc ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c id
May 28 18:21:18 fgv246 sudo: em12c-srvc : sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/em12c-srvc ; USER=em12c-srvc ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that tty is required. So a hack around it is:

As root:

```
 ./install.sh -u 
  visudo /etc/sudoers 
  comment out: #Default requiretty
   And reinstall (./install.sh)
```

You dont have to use vim but you get the idea. Uncomment the line after installation

Comment: That did the trick !! but i still have a doubt !! How can i do this for only one user and not apply the rule for all of them ?

Comment: found the solution should be something like this: default :username !requiretty

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the environment variable TTY, I think like TTY=/dev/tty0